# IntelliJ14, Scala, and Gradle integration

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project that use Scala 2.10.4 and Gradle 1.6.  I just upgraded from IntelliJ 12.1.15 where everything worked to IntelliJ 14.0.1 and now I cannot run the Scala code through the IDE.  I tried to create a simple new project with a single Scala object that extended App and printed "Hello world."  I can run it through IntelliJ just fine.  As soon as I add a simple build.gradle file though, I cannot run the Scala any more.  It keeps giving me the error message:

> "Unable to make the module: X, related gradle configuration was not
>   found.  Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again."

I have tried that and everything I can think of over and over again, but I keep getting to the same point.  Does anyone have any suggestions for getting past this?  I can run the Gradle build through IntelliJ just fine, but not being able to actually run the Scala through IntelliJ sort of defeats the purpose of having an IDE in the first place because I cannot debug at all.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I recommend to raise an issue for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: So closing the project and re-importing it didn't work?

Comment: Same issue on 14.1.5 with JDK 8.  I tried deleting all IDEA files and recreating the IDEA project using the gradle IDEA plugin, I tried deleting all IDEA files and simply opening the project.  I am able to refresh the gradle project in IDEA, and run all of the external tasks successfully.  When I right click and try to run a known-good test, I see "Error:  Unable to make module: ... related gradle configuration was not found."

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with Intellij 14.03.
The following is why I got the problem.
1. I created a project and it worked well.
2. I copied the project to another directory.
3. I used Intellij(File->Open) to open the project to make module.
4. Then, it didn't work and gave me the problem.

I solved it by the way:
1.Open Intellij and import the project(File->Import Project).
2.After that, it will be successful to make.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IDEA Ultimate but then I tried on Community edition and it worked fine. Maybe it was IDEA version, or maybe there was different scala/gradle version. I am using IDEA 14.0.2, Scala 2.11.4, gradle 2.2.1 (I think)